# No puedo consultar todos los datos en un fichero txt en C

Tags: c, archivo, registro

tengo un problema, estoy haciendo una consulta de datos en un fichero txt y cuando tengo mas de un dato en el fichero al momento de consultar me dice que dicho dato no existe... Por ejemplo Si yo tengo el registro a con el codigo 1 y el registro b con el codigo 2 si quiero consultar codigo 2 me dice que no se ha encontrado informacion relacionada a dicho codigo. Estoy leyendo mi archivo con el fscanf y leo hasta el final del archivo pero nose que puede estar pasando?

Estructura:

```
typedef struct {
    int cedula;
    char nombre[15];
    int  diab;
    int  mesb;
    int  anob;
}personas;
```

Funcion ingreso de datos:

```
    char resp;
    char fech[10];
    char cedu[10];
    
    FILE *f;
    personas personas;
    system("cls");
    printf("\t\tIntroduzca el nombre de la persona\n");
    printf (" ->"); fgets(personas.nombre,15,stdin);
    verif(personas.nombre);
    fflush(stdin);
    
    
    printf("\t\tIntroduzca la cedula de la persona\n");
    printf (" ->"); fgets(cedu,10,stdin);
    verif(cedu);
    
    if (let(cedu)){
        printf("\nLa cedula digitada contiene caracteres\n");
        printf("\nRegresando al menu PERSONAS...\n");
        system ("pause");
        system ("cls");
        personasS();        
    }
    personas.cedula = atoi(cedu);
    fflush(stdin);
f=fopen("PersonasInfo.txt","a");
        if (f!=NULL){
            fprintf(f,"%s\n",personas.nombre);
            fprintf(f,"%d\n",personas.cedula);
} //SON MUCHOS MAS DATOS PERO NO LOS PONGO PARA HACER LA PREGUNTA LEGIBLE
```

Consulta:

```
FILE *f ;
personas personas;
int band = 0;

f = fopen("PersonasInfo.txt","r");
char nom[15];
system("cls");
printf("Digite el nombre a buscar "); printf (" -> ");
fgets(nom,15,stdin);
verif(nom);

while ( (!feof(f)) && (fscanf(f,"%s %d",personas.nombre,&personas.cedula) ){
    if ((strstr(nom,personas.nombre)!=NULL) && band==0){
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\t--- D A T O S   E N C O N T R A D O S ---\n");
        printf("\tNombre: %s\n",personas.nombre);
        printf("\tCedula de identidad: %d\n",personas.cedula);
        band = 1;
        printf("\n");
        system("pause");
        personasS();
    }else if (band == 0 ) {
        system("cls");
        printf("No se encuentra una persona con ese nombre. Volviendo a menu personas\n");
        system("pause");
        personasS();
    }
}
system("pause");
fclose(f);
```

Y bueno la funcion imprimir que dudo que tenga algo que ver..

```
FILE *archivo;
char caracter;

archivo=fopen("PersonasInfo.txt","r");
system("cls");
while ( (caracter=fgetc(archivo))!=EOF)
{
    putchar(caracter);
}
system("pause");
fclose(archivo);
system("pause");
personasS();
```

Comment: Se agradece el esfuerzo que haces al escribir la pregunta, pero cuando nos dices que lo que muestras es un código parcial haces muy difícil que te ayudemos. Por ejemplo, el `fscanf(f,"%s\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",personas.nombre,&personas.cedula)` no se corresponde con el código de escritura de fichero, ya que en ese código solo guardas dos valores (pero entonces comentas que guardas mucho más en código que no vemos). Mira como hacer un [mcve], por ejemplo modificando el programa para que solo guarde el nombre y ver si así lo encuentra, y si tienes problemas nos pones el programa TAL COMO LO PRUEBAS.

Comment: Hola, lo que guardo ahi ademas del nombre y la cedula es la fecha de nacimiento separada en 3 integers. El problema que tengo es que guardo un registro completo, y ese primer registro mi programa si me lo encuentra a la hora de consultar pero cuando tienes otro registro y consultas no te da resultados.

Comment: Ya lo acabo de editar a ver si se entiende un poco mejor lo que quiero preguntar

Comment: Estás haciendo los `fprintf` separando los campos por `\n` pero al leer el `fscanf` espera que los campos estén separados por un espacio en blanco. Además, si no encuentras el registro a la primera el `else if` se ejecuta inmediatamente; la comprobación de si no se ha encontrado al recorrer todo el fichero debería estar fuera del bucle.

Comment: En ese caso entonces, el fscanf deberia tener tambien los campos con el '\n' ? Es decir si lo pongo en el mismo formato que salen en el fprintf no deberia haber problemas para que me devuelva la consulta no?

Comment: Estoy probando lo del if fuera y por ahora me funciona te aviso cualquier cosa. gracias

Comment: Correctísimo amigo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!